# How do you determine if an insert or update was successful using Java and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert-update

I am using Java to connect to a MySQL database.  I am trying to insert or update data into the database.

Even though I am quite sure the insert was successful, it returns false.

According to the "execute" API, the return value is "true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results".

How can I determine whether or not my insert or update was successful?

```
    public boolean insertSelections(String selection, String name){
        String sql ="INSERT INTO WORKREPORT VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        boolean action = false;
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy：MM：dd hh:mm:ss");
            String formatDate = dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
            java.util.Date mDate = dateFormat.parse(formatDate);
            java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
//          Date time= new Date(mDate.getTime());

            stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(getNumberByName(name).trim()));
            stmt.setString(2, name);
//          stmt.setDate(3, time);
            stmt.setTimestamp(3, timeStamp);
            stmt.setString(4, selection);
            stmt.setString(5, "N/A");
            action = stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return action;
    }
```

Comment: Try with `stmt.executeUpdate();` for kind of `Update op(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you are using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) you can call `executeUpdate()` -

```
 int count = stmt.executeUpdate();
 action = (count > 0); // <-- something like this.
```

From the Javadoc (*Returns*) link above, emphasis added,

> either (1) *the **row count** for SQL Data Manipulation Language* (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing.

If you want to insert a large number of entries, I would prefer [`addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and [`executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29).

Answer (score 21):

First of all this you should know :

**boolean execute()**
Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.

**ResultSet executeQuery()**
Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

**int executeUpdate()**
Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

```
        int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.println("success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("stuck somewhere");
        }
```

Try this and check it out whether insert is happening or not

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get a exception I think query is went ok. 
Or, you might be able to use executeUpdate() ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) )

You can do a select count(*) do validate number of records if you want.

Comment: I'm currently running a delete query which should remove 1 record in my test. The query does pass, however it does return 0 changed records. Therefor this isn't correct.

SELECT count(*) would work, but is not required.

Comment: @Mathieu Brouwers It is not suitable for update and delete statement, but for insert statement it should work. If you don't get a exception, that means insert query went OK. Please, let me know if I am missing anything about insert queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, whether you want to know whether the data is inserted or not , if the record is inserted it return true or else false.

```
  if(action > 0){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
      }
```